# Calculate $\iint_A\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}dxdy$ with $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x^2+y^2\le1, 0\le x\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x^2+y^2\le1, 0\le x\}$
>
> Calculate $\iint_A\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}dxdy$

I'm doing that problem from an exam, and the solution is the following:

> Use polar coordinates, $x=r\cos(\theta),y=r\sin(\theta).$ Then we use a
> change of variables $u=1+r^2$ and we get:
>
> $\iint_A\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+r^2}\,dr\,d\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{1}^{2}\frac{1}{u}du=\frac{\pi \log(2)}{2}$

Yet, I did the following:

> $\iint_A\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+r^2}\,dr\,d\theta=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\pi}{4}\,d\theta=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$

Where is the error which clearly I'm not seeing?

Comment: Where is your Jacobian?

Comment: You are missing $r$ as a factor, which is the Jacobian as @NinadMunshi has mentioned.

Comment: $dxdy \iff rdrd\theta$ for polar.

Comment: I am an idiot, thank you.